# Why does Bower say Angular depends on random things?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am trying to install a package, for instance `bower install restangular --save`

Then Bower asks me to choose an Angular version:

```
> Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
>     1) angular#1.2.6 which resolved to 1.2.6 and has ang-changeorg, angular-cookies#1.2.6, angular-mocks#1.2.6, angular-resource#1.2.6,
> angular-sanitize#1.2.6, angular-scenario#1.2.6 as dependants
>     2) angular#1.2.17-build.226+sha.b6388b3 which resolved to 1.2.17-build.226+sha.b6388b3 and has angular-animate#1.2.17-build.226+sha.b6388b3 as dependants
>     3) angular#* which resolved to 1.2.18 and has restangular#1.4.0 as dependants
>     4) angular#~1.2.0 which resolved to 1.2.19-build.258+sha.ea653e4 and has angularfire#0.7.1 as dependants
>     5) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.3.0-build.2845+sha.e57ad6a and has angular-ui-router#0.2.10 as dependants
> 
> Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

In these options `ang-changeorg` is another project I've worked on locally, has no relation to my current working directory.

My `bower.json` for the current project looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "ang-changeorg",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "appPath": "public",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "firebase": "~1.0.11",
    "angularfire": "~0.7.1",
    "spin.js": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.16",
    "ng-file-upload": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.6"
  }
}
```

`bower cache clean` did not resolve this.

Why does bower list `ang-changeorg` as a dependent? Clarity on how these angularjs version dependents work would be awesome.

Comment: I haven't used bower in a long time, but this looks like your current project may seated in a directory under your ang-chageorg. So it is assuming that the top project cache is the one it should be copying from. You can test this by renaming all of your bower.json files to bower.json.old, then try again.

Comment: Could I ask that you write your titles in standard sentence case, with the necessary caps for names for things? It may seem like a small thing, but nearly all of your titles are all-lower-case, and this adds edit effort when someone improves your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because in your bower.json, the name of your project is ang-changeorg

`{
  "name": "ang-changeorg",
  "version":`

And all the dependencies in that file

`"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",`

...

are the ones "name": "ang-changeorg" are dependent to.
Therefore ang-changeorg is dependent to angular#1.2.6 because the version 1.2.6 of angular is specified in your bower file:

`"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",`

Comment: i didn't see I used the wrong project name! Thanks for spotting

Answer (score 4):

**Each package listed in your `bower.json` file has it's own `bower.json` file which lists another set of dependencies**.

So, when it says that `ang-changeorg` has `angular#1.2.6` as a dependant, that's because the `ang-changeorg` package has `angular#1.2.6` listed in it's `bower.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

Consider upgrading to latest Angular 1.2.18 in all of your Bower calls, you've got some mixed dependencies and most likely Restangular would prefer the latest or at least matching with the latest version ("angular-animate": "~1.2.16").
I don't think you'll see any breaking changes.